# Why are legislatures called by their native language names but not heads of government?

Tags: loanwords, localization

Why do English-language news articles and other sources often refer to legislatures or legislative chambers by their name in the predominant language of the country (Lok Sabha, Duma, Knesset, Diet, Folketing, and historically Reichstag, Supreme Soviet), but almost always refer to the head of government by an English title such as prime minister or president? (The only exception seems to be Taoiseach, but that's in the English-language constitution so it might not even be an exception.)

Comment: We don’t always: e.g. Japan’s National Diet isn’t called that in Japanese

Comment: *but almost always refer to the head of government by an English title such as prime minister or president?* What is the title of the equivalent rank of Prime Minister/President in (a) Burmese (b) Finnish, (c) Hungarian (d) Kyrgyz? Are you seriously expecting all English speakers to learn the native-language titles of all nations? Do you seriously think that the average English speaker would be able to pronounce half of these?

Comment: In some of these cases it's metonymy: the Reichstag isn't the actual government, it's a name for the building used as a figure of speech. In other cases, it fulfils a similar role - that of variety. You can alternate "the Chancellor" and "Scholz", but having to say "German government" over and over would be boring, when "Reichstag" can be substituted.  Also, French for President is Président, German is Präsident, and Dutch is President, so not much point substituting that. (Some terms, such as Soviet, are a bit different, but that's another question.)

Comment: @Greybeard No, but I don't know the names of the legislatures in those countries either, just the ones most commonly discussed in English (and I'm sure I'm mispronouncing even those).

Comment: Yes, we use non-English words for legislatures more than for heads of government, but not very often. There is a list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legislatures_by_number_of_members. (I did a rough count, and it looks like less than 10%.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Even when I sort that list by population, I don't think they appear in English-language media in that order. The Knesset is way down at #99 by population but seems to mentioned in the news more than many above it. Also a chamber of a bicameral legislature (e.g. Lok Sabha, Duma) often seems to be in the news more than the whole legislature but is naturally not included in this list.

Comment: @herisson Thanks, I didn't realize Diet was English.

Comment: @LeeC. But one could also reverse that argument: The top 10 by population includes Bangladesh's "Jatiya Sangsad", which I can't recall hearing or reading about in any English-language media (at least here in the U.S.). In any case, it's a relatively minor point; I was only taking issue with the word "often".